# 2000 Jeep Cherokee 2WD battery light comes on

Tags: battery, jeep, lights, cherokee

I recently purchased a 2000 Jeep Cherokee, and I live in Syracuse NY, where the winters are pretty cold. When I start it in the morning when it's cold out, the serpentine belt and tensioner need to be replaced, so they squeak, but the battery light comes on and it doesn't go off unless I shut off the car. I know the Cherokees are known for having electrical problems but I have no idea.

Comment: Does the light go out after the engine has run for a while?

Comment: Have you put a multimeter on the alternator to see if it's putting out any juice?

Comment: "Does the light go out after the engine has run for a while? – mikes" No, I would have to turn the vehicle off then turn it back on again, but If I let the vehicle warm up for a bit then the light doesnt come on at all.

Comment: No I have not tried to put a multimeter on the vehicle.